# Why doesn't x fully reach y in while(x < y)

Tags: unity, c#

I have the following code in a coroutine

```
float percent = 0;

while(percent < 1) {
    Debug.Log(percent);

    percent += Time.deltaTime;
    yield return null;
}
```

However, percent never reaches or passes 1 (stops around ~0.98). How can I make sure that the while loop doesn't end until percent reaches 1?

Comment: Note where your log is

Comment: Please note that if you are using floats you should append a `f` to the numerical value `float percent = 0f;`. Same when you do the comparison `while(percent < 1f) {`

Comment: The log was just put in for the purpose of this post. Adding the f in helped fix the issue though. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, gonna post as an answer in this case :)

Comment: If the log was just for the purpose of the post, maybe better to put it **after** incrementing `percent`, else it becomes really confusing for us

Comment: Hey, sorry, I had to rollback your question, I feel that it makes the most upvoted answer here completely irrelevant. The way you question is written now makes both of the most upvoted question relevant and useful for future visitors: either they didn't use the proper type, or they did not order their call correctly.

Comment: _"Adding the f in __helped__ fix the issue though."_ Did you do something else to fix the issue? Or is the loop in your implementation different than the one posted here? The currently accepted answer defies logic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer was initially a simple comment. I poster an answer as **OP said it fixed his problem**.*

When using floats you should append a `f` at the end of the numerical value, in your case :

```
float percent = 0f;

while(percent < 1f) {
    percent += Time.deltaTime;
    yield return null;
}
```

It is possible that your problem **has nothing to do with that, but it is just good practice!**

Comment: Where is the `double` in `percent < 1`? Since the only floating point value here is `percent`, which is a `float`, why wouldn't the 1 be implicitly converted to `float` instead of `double` _then_ `float`?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I am not sure how it works in C#, but in C++ I would write it `percent < 1.f`. Maybe different writing means different behaviour, but in C++ if you forget to append the `f` it is by default considered as a double. As I said, this answer was just a comment and the OP told me it soved his problem, but thx for the -1 :)

Comment: _"it is by default considered as a double."_ No, in c++ `1` is considered an `int`, not a `double`. `1.0` would be considered a `double`.

Comment: And unfortunately, you can't assume that getting a comment to your answer, _and_ a downvote, that it's the same person who did both. I did not downvote this answer.

Comment: In C# 1 is int, 1.0 is double and 1.0f is float. Adding the f probably wasn't the correct fix, and the OP did something else too that actually fixed the problem.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I meant `1.` not `1`. As OP said it fixed his problem I simply tried to find an explanation, as originally my comment was only about good practice when writing code

Comment: I completely agree with the good practices you're talking about. And please do not take my comments personally, it's just very odd, to me and probably to the other users who downvoted, that this fixed the issue in any way. I'm trying to see with the OP if they did something else that could fix the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Your log function is **before** the increase of the value of `percent`. So the final value of percent is never logged.

The final time round the loop would look like this

```
while(percent < 1) { 
    Debug.Log(percent); //percent is 0.98, 0.98 is logged

    percent += Time.deltaTime; //deltaTime is say 0.03, so percent is now 1.01
    yield return null;

    //percent is 1.01, loop will exit and 1.01 is never logged 
    //(despite being the value of percent at the end of the loop

}
```

`percent` is now larger than 1, but its not logged after the loop, just at the **beginning** of each loop

Comment: This is the correct answer. The difference in precision between floats and doubles is negligible for mundane values (e.g. not in the tens of thousands).

Comment: @Kroltan As far as I understood, OP is not complaining about not being able to log 1 or more, but about leaving the loop and then realizing `percent` is lower than 1 still. As he stated himself `The log was just put in for the purpose of this post.`

Comment: @realUser404 Rather annoyingly I've answered the question the user asked, but (possibly) not the one the user wanted to ask (and bizarrely still is asking). I'm not entirely convinced by the float vs double thing with the quoted 0.98 end point though, that's a long way from 1. If it was 0.99..99 then maybe

Comment: I do not know I am pretty surprised too, I thought your answer was correct, I even upvoted you and then just made a comment, but if he says adding the `f` is fixing the issue...

Comment: +1. I think this is the right answer, I'd assume OP fixed both and only then has a complete solution.